# fill two dimensional array with unique random number with java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any way to fill two dimensional array with unique random number ? I tried so much but all of my tries are failed .
I can do this

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {         //element will be in range (1,25)
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(j) + "     ");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to print a 5x5 matrix of numbers from the `List`, you just need two layers of `for` loops. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/27nnAq).

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) { // element will be in range (1,25)
    list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        System.out.format("%3d     ", list.get(j * 5 + k));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();
```

**Example Output:**

```
  3       4      23      18      15     
  1       8      20       6       7     
  5      21      19       2      24     
 17      13      22      16      25     
 14       9      12      10      11
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use combination of library which generates the random number and hashset. Hashset to remember the random number generated so far, and if duplicate is generated, you re-generate until it gives you the unseen number

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static List<List<Integer>> uniqueRandomNumbers(int height, int width) {
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, height * width)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    List<List<Integer>> matrix = IntStream.range(0, height)
        .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i * width, (i + 1) * width))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return matrix;
}
```

and

```
List<List<Integer>> matrix = uniqueRandomNumbers(5, 5);
for (List<Integer> list : matrix)
    System.out.println(list);
```

result

```
[16, 4, 15, 14, 25]
[19, 11, 6, 21, 9]
[17, 20, 3, 1, 5]
[10, 7, 22, 18, 2]
[12, 13, 24, 23, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this can help ?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // declare arrays
      int[][] ticketInfo;
      String[][] seatingChart;

      // create arrays
      ticketInfo = new int [2][3];
      seatingChart =  new String [3][2];

      // initialize the array elements
      ticketInfo[0][0] = 15;
      ticketInfo[0][1] = 10;
      ticketInfo[0][2] = 15;
      ticketInfo[1][0] = 25;
      ticketInfo[1][1] = 20;
      ticketInfo[1][2] = 25;
      seatingChart[0][0] = "Jamal";
      seatingChart[0][1] = "Maria";
      seatingChart[1][0] = "Jacob";
      seatingChart[1][1] = "Suzy";
      seatingChart[2][0] = "Emma";
      seatingChart[2][1] = "Luke";

      // print the contents
      System.out.println(ticketInfo);
      System.out.println(seatingChart);
   }
```

Comment: it'll not work because "ticketInfo" and "seatingChart" are arrays and in printing you called them as variable and if we call them in loop it will print the values which we set it for them